# How to echo rows values in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo values of each row.
I tried this...  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc) {...}
but it prints the last value of row each time in a specific part of the loop.
Also, I created an array an I assigned the values in the while loop but it didn't work.
Can you please help me?

```
$query= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM db WHERE user='$user' AND deleted='no' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$link="index.php?id=". $row['id']; //wrong value

if ($row["user"] == 'User 1') {

$id=$row['id'];
$tags=$row['tags'];
$token = strtok($tags, ",");



echo "<div class='thisdiv'>
<a href='../games/avery/index.php?id=$id'><img src='../images/games/Preview.png ' ></a><br><p class='font-size-bold'>Tags</p>"; //correct $id
```

Comment: it will echo all the data but may be you shown last one or replace on loop.

Comment: _“Can you please help me?”_ - not with what you have currently given us. What you actually want to achieve here is very unclear, or what exactly is supposed to be wrong. Please go read [ask], and then try and explain the problem a bit better.

Comment: please provide query fields

Comment: I am trying to create links (stored as text values in db). But the problem is that the stored text has always the last value of row.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Inject is allowed with your code, use statament for exclude this possible:

```
$query= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM db WHERE user=? AND deleted=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
$no='no';
$query->bind_param('ss',$user,$no);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if ($row["user"] == 'User 1') {

$id=$row['id'];
$tags=$row['tags'];
$token = strtok($tags, ",");



echo "<div class='thisdiv'><a href='../games/avery/index.php?id=$id'><img src='../images/games/Preview.png ' ></a><br><p class='font-size-bold'>Tags</p>"; //correct $id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite limited but will try to break it down for you.

So first things first your query is working. And you get the 6 last results from your table since you order in `DESC` and `LIMIT` to 6

You while loop also loops around your fetched results. So your issue is more logical.

The 1st iteration of your while will set value to variable `$link` like:

```
$link="index.php?id=". $row['id'];
```

This will always be executed on every iteration (6 times) and actually your variable will be overwritten, so at the last iteration `$link` is going to have the id of the last element.

In your code after that you have a check:

```
    if ($row["user"] == 'User 1') {

    $id=$row['id'];
    $tags=$row['tags'];
    $token = strtok($tags, ",");

    echo "<a href='../games/avery/index.php?id=$id'><img src='../images/games/Preview.png ' ></a><br><p class='font-size-bold'>Tags</p>"; 

} // mind the closing bracket, you echo your validated value
```

That's where i think you are getting it wrong. This echo should be inside your if check but also your variable link should be in there.